# Is there any software for flashing nokia mobile phones ? 

Tags: software-recommendation, nokia

Is there any software in linux for flashing nokia mobile phones ?

Comment: Well, which type of Nokia phones? Symbian phones, Maemo (N900) or Harmattan (N9) ?

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't one available for Linux, you are mostly stuck with Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the phones will use a USB connection for flashing.

If possible, one of the solutions will be to use Windows inside VirtualBox for that effect.

You can configure VirtualBox to pass the USB connection with the phone directly to the virtual machine.